# ssh-agent denies to add root's private key with sudo user

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Is there a way to add root's ssh **private key** in **ssh-agent**, with a standard **sudo user**?

I'm not really sure, but is this the restriction with this command?

In the **ssh-add man page** I found this:
*Identity files should not be readable by anyone but the user.  Note that ssh-add ignores identity files if they are accessible by others.*

Thats the output:

```
sudouser@myhost:/ $ ssh-agent

SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Yppfd3Xp0Yrm/agent.2429; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2430; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2430;

sudouser@myhost:/ $ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 2435

sudouser@myhost:/ $ ssh-add /home/sudouser/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/sudouser/.ssh/id_rsa:                                                                                                                                      
Identity added: /home/sudouser/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/sudouser/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Works as expected.
But with root's key i get:

```
sudouser@myhost:/ sudo ssh-add /root/.ssh/ansible/id_rsa

or

sudouser@myhost:/ sudo sh -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/ansible/id_rsa'

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` clears environment variables. `ssh-add` needs SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID in order to know how to speak to `ssh-agent`. So you must trick it by adding them back in the command:

```
sudo sh -c 'export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="'"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"'"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="'"$SSH_AGENT_PID"'"; ssh-add /path/to/roots/private/key'
```

Comment: Thank you very much (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412986/alexp) . Thats exactly for what I had looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Possible alternative answer, sudo has a option to preserve environment variables:

```bash
sudo --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK -i
```

Alternatively you can add this line to the sudoers file to get the same effect:

```bash
Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Comment: very convenient!